# Книги по питону

Tags: python, книги

Скачал три книги по питону: Саммерфилда, Лутца и Бизли. 
Какую из них стоит прочитать ?

Answer (score 3):

В порядке: Лутц - Саммерфильд - Бизли.

Comment: @mikillskegg, а я их тоже (примеры заразительны) сейчас скачал и поглядел. Все собираюсь заняться питоном, но пока все никак... 

--

Так, в Лутце аж 1200 страниц(!) и в остальных 2-х по 800 с хвостиком.

Я понимаю, что Саммерфельд это Python-3, а Бизли - справочник.

Но, как считаете, может будет достаточно что-то одно из них (которые по 800) прочесть?

Comment: Лутц читается как роман. Я его за полтора месяца одолел. Думаю, лучше начать с него.

Comment: OK, попробую.

Comment: Осваивайте технику быстрого чтения, тогда выбирать книжку с меньшим кол-вом страниц не прийдется.

Comment: @zhenyab, если все эти страницы по делу, то не жалко. 

Просто в последние лет десять (а то и больше) в большинстве книг *очень много* "воды".

Comment: А какой Лутц? Программируем на Python или Изучаем Python? Очень разные книги.

Comment: Ну, если синтаксис нужен и особенности, тогда Изучаем Python. Если, необходима практика со встроенными модулями и понимание того, зачем вообще Python используется, тогда вторая. Все же просто.

Comment: Видимо нужны обе. 

To: @mikillskegg, заодно уж и 2 тома "программирования" в pdf-e качнул. Попробую почитать.

Answer (score 2):

Бизли - скорее справочник по модулям.
Сначала Лутц ("Изучаем Python"). Потом, кстати, можно еще Лутца прочитать, двухтомник "Программирование на Python".

Есть еще, кстати, неплохая книжка "Python в системном администрировании UNIX и Linux", авторы - Ноа Гифт и Джереми М. Джонс, но она уже несколько профильная.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что стоит начать с книги самого автора языка: Гвидо ван Россум, Ф. Л. Дж. Дрейк, Денис Откидач. Язык программирования Python.

Comment: Тоже скачал и уже поглядел. Начало похоже на Бизли (очевидно, правильней *наоборот*). 

Но у Бизли как-то повеселей и сразу более живые примерчики:

    for line in open(“foo.txt”):
      print line

на стр 29(!!!),

 но у Россума на первых, скажем, 50-ти страницах "по делу" IMHO  базовой информации побольше...

Возможно их надо читать в параллель. 

А вот Лутц производит впечатление весьма занудного препода. Читаешь, понимаешь, что это по большей части "пустое", надо бы пробежать дальше, но опасаешься, что потом надо будет возвращаться.

(вот такие первые впечатления).

Answer (score 0):

Купил Бизли, не жалею. Только им и пользуюсь.

Comment: Да, Бизли хорош, но только после прочтения Лутца.
Лутц читается один раз, а дальше Бизли в руки - и вперед.

Comment: Это если ты не знаешь вообще ничего. Я начал учиться прогать с осваивания алгоритмов(алгоритмизация и программирование на Python). Потом сразу на Бизли перелез. Нормально. У Бизли воды почти нету, только сухая информация.

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть на досуге: [Хахаев И.А.](http://www.altlinux.ru/products/books/python-book/)